# iOS using OpenGL shaders in CIKernel

Tags: ios, opengl-es, cikernel

Is it possible to use OpenGL shaders in iOS using **CIKernel** ?
If not, is there a way to convert between the two ?

Example OpenGL Shader

```
 #extension GL_OES_EGL_image_external : require
precision mediump float;
varying vec2 vTextureCoord;
uniform samplerExternalOES sTexture;
void main() {
    vec4 textureColor = texture2D(sTexture, vTextureCoord);
    vec4 outputColor;
    outputColor.r = (textureColor.r * 0.393) + (textureColor.g * 0.769) + (textureColor.b * 0.189);
    outputColor.g = (textureColor.r * 0.349) + (textureColor.g * 0.686) + (textureColor.b * 0.168);
    outputColor.b = (textureColor.r * 0.272) + (textureColor.g * 0.534) + (textureColor.b * 0.131);
    outputColor.a = 1.0;
    gl_FragColor = outputColor;
```

I am trying to use the same filters for iOS and android. Android already uses OpenGL shaders, so I would like to use the same shaders in my iOS app.

Comment: I think a proper answer would tell you how rather than literally answering the question but, time being what it is, all I've time to say is: yes, that's exactly what CIKernel is for. So that you can use GLSL to perform an image modification without having to muck about otherwise reproducing your UI in OpenGL. So: yes. Yes you can.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can, but with a few tweaks.

- `vTextureCoord` and `samplerExternalOES` would be passed into a kernel function as arguments.
- The `sTexture` type would be `__sample` (assuming you're using a `CIColorKernel` which means the kernel can only access the pixel currently being computed)
- For a color kernel, the function declaration would be `kernel vec4 xyzzy(__sample pixel)` - you can't name it `main`.
- You don't need `texture2D` in a color kernel. In the example above `pixel` holds the color of the current pixel.
- Rather than setting the value of `gl_FragColor`, your kernel function needs to return the color as a `vec4`.

If you want to use your code verbatim, you could (at a stretch) consider a Sprite Kit `SKShader` to generate a `SKTexture` which can be rendered as a `CGImage`.

simon

Comment: Simon Gladman can you please share any guides/docs that explains how to convert shaders to CIKernel?